# Can I run a OIDC flow from a command line CLI tool?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, onelogin

I'm running an OIDC flow to get access and ID tokens on a single-page application (I use OneLogin but that's probably not very relevant, it's a vanilla OIDC flow). I use the access token to call my backend APIs.

I want to provide the same functionality (including calling the same backend) from a command line tool. Is there a standard way to get the access token the same way I do it in the browser?

I'd consider any solutions including completing part of the flow in the browser, alternatives to OIDC, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A console app is a native app and can run a code flow and listen for the OAuth response using one of the techniques from [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.1):

- Loopback URL, eg http:/localhost:8000/callback
- Private URI scheme URL, eg x-myapp:/callback

Here is some partial Javascript code for the first case. For an example of the second case see my [desktop code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final).

```js
import Http from 'http';
import Opener from 'opener';

export async function login(): Promise<string> {

    const codeVerifier = generateRandomString();
    const codeChallenge = generateHash(codeVerifier);
    const state = generateRandomString();
    const authorizationUrl = buildAuthorizationUrl(state, codeChallenge);

    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {

        let server: Http.Server | null = null;
        const callback = async (request: Http.IncomingMessage, response: Http.ServerResponse) => {

            if (server != null) {

                response.write('Login completed for the console client ...');
                response.end();
                server.close();
                server = null;

                try {

                    // Swap the code for tokens
                    const accessToken = await redeemCodeForAccessToken(request.url!, state, codeVerifier);
                    resolve(accessToken);

                } catch (e: any) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            }
        }

        server = Http.createServer(callback);
        server.listen(loopbackPort);
        
        Opener(authorizationUrl);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Onelogin has a couple of tools that can help in this process. (I'm on the OIDC engineering team). You can do part of the process through the OIDC [Inspector Tool](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/inspector).

That might not give you exactly what you are looking for, writing your own script may be the best option. If that is the route you take, I suggest looking at the [Postman Collections](https://www.postman.com/onelogin/workspace/onelogin-s-public-workspace/overview)

Feel free to reach out if I can be of more assistance